# push notifications ionic 2 for android

Tags: push-notification, ionic2

I need to configure push notifications for an Ionic 2 application for android devices.

I read [here](https://medium.com/@ankushaggarwal/push-notifications-in-ionic-2-658461108c59#.24b9o70rv) that in order to do that you need to login to Firebase console, create a project and so on...

So my question is, do I really need to log into Firebase to do this? I'm not using firebase in my app, so I don´t get why I need to create a project to get a SERVER_ID and SERVER_KEY. What if I delete that project in Firebase afterwards, then my push notifications will stop working?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you do need an account to use Firebase Cloud Messaging because you'll need a key to send pushs.
You need the key to use device-to-device push via HTTP and you need a project to send notifications to a group or topics.

I don't think that there's a way to use push without creating an account in any service.

Comment: Ok, that was what I was talking about. Even if I use another service, Ionic cloud or azure or whatever, I still need a key to send the notifications, and the only way to get it is through Firebase.
It doesn´t really make sense to me...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a Firebase account.

You can use azure notifications hub or amazon aws or google cloud service, ionic cloud, etc.

Any cloud services that provides a notification hub which is basically a **server** for receiving and redistributing to the registered parties to the specific platforms.

Please note that some of these are specifically mobile oriented meaning you wont have to write any server side code and others aren't.